# essential norm versus invertibility

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space and $T:X\rightarrow X$ be a bounded linear operator. If $T$ is invertible and $\lVert T\rVert_e=\lVert T\rVert$, is it true that (or when is it true that) $\lVert T^{-1}\rVert=\lVert T^{-1}\rVert_e$? Here, $\lVert\cdot\rVert_e$ denotes the essential norm.

Comment: It is certainly not true in general.  For example, write $X$ as the direct sum of an infinite dimensional closed subspace $Y$ and a one dimensional subspace $Z$ and consider an operator that is the identity on $Y$ and a small positive multiple of the identity on $Z$, so that in the Calkin algebra the operator is the identity element.